# Exercise 6 of Chapter 12 (Tuples) of Think Python by Allen Dwney

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I'm learning python from Think Python by Allen Downey and I'm stuck at Exercise 6 [here](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython013.html#toc141). I wrote a solution to it, and at first look it seemed to be an improvement over the answer given [here](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/code/reducible.py). But upon running both, I found that my solution took a whole day (~22 hours) to compute the answer, while the author's solution only took a couple seconds.
Could anyone tell me *how* the author's solution is so fast, when it iterates over a dictionary containing 113,812 words and applies a recursive function to each to compute a result?

My solution:

```
known_red = {'sprite': 6, 'a': 1, 'i': 1, '': 0}  #Global dict of known reducible words, with their length as values

def compute_children(word):
   """Returns a list of all valid words that can be constructed from the word by removing one letter from the word"""
    from dict_exercises import words_dict
    wdict = words_dict() #Builds a dictionary containing all valid English words as keys
    wdict['i'] = 'i'
    wdict['a'] = 'a'
    wdict[''] = ''
    res = []

    for i in range(len(word)):
        child = word[:i] + word[i+1:]
        if nword in wdict:
            res.append(nword)

    return res

def is_reducible(word):
    """Returns true if a word is reducible to ''. Recursively, a word is reducible if any of its children are reducible"""
    if word in known_red:
        return True
    children = compute_children(word)

    for child in children:
        if is_reducible(child):
            known_red[word] = len(word)
            return True
    return False

def longest_reducible():
    """Finds the longest reducible word in the dictionary"""
    from dict_exercises import words_dict
    wdict = words_dict()
    reducibles = []

    for word in wdict:
        if 'i' in word or 'a' in word: #Word can only be reducible if it is reducible to either 'I' or 'a', since they are the only one-letter words possible
            if word not in known_red and is_reducible(word):
                known_red[word] = len(word)

    for word, length in known_red.items():
        reducibles.append((length, word))

    reducibles.sort(reverse=True)

    return reducibles[0][1]
```

Comment: You make the same `words_dict` every time `compute_children` or `longest_reducible` is run. Try doing that just once.

Comment: and once you've done Junuxx's suggestion you could also try testing words longest first and stopping as soon as you find one that is reducible. That would mean you can ignore many of the words altogether.

Comment: Python's `profile` module will tell you where your code is spending its time and is a tool worth learning how to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
wdict = words_dict() #Builds a dictionary containing all valid English words...
```

Presumably, this takes a while.

However, **you regenerate this same, unchanging dictionary many times**  for every word you try to reduce. What a waste! If you make this dictionary once, and then re-use that dictionary for every word you try to reduce like you do for `known_red`, the computation time should be greatly reduced.

Comment: Wow, didn't know it took that amount of time to do a task that on its own was done quickly. But I suppose it snowballed, what with all of those recursive calls.Thanks!

Comment: @blindingflashofawesome: Just curious, how long does it take now that you fixed this? :)

Comment: No longer than 4 seconds. And to think I wasted an entire day doing nothing else on the computer!